# How To Print Spaces Or Left And Right Align Content On One Line From Android To Receipt Printer Over Bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, printing, alignment, spaces

[image: Spacing issue on the receipt]

```
for (i=0;i<items.length;i++){
        String line;
        padding = 50-items[i].length();
        int words = items[i].split("\\s+").length;
        Log.i("info","words: " + words);
        if (words==2) padding += words-1;
        else if (words==3) padding += words-2;
        else if (words==4) padding += words-2;
        //line = String.format("%55s%s", items[i], prices[i]);
        Log.i("info","padding:" + padding);
        //for (int x=0;x<padding;x++) line +="-";
        line = String.format("%1$-" + padding + "s", items[i]);
        tempContent += line + "P" + prices[i] + "\n";
        total +=  Double.parseDouble(prices[i]);
    }
    tempContent += "-----------\n";
    tempContent += String.format("%1$-" + 28 + "s", "Total");
    tempContent += Double.toString(total);
    final String orderContent = tempContent;
// then sending to the print function
print.sendData("Table " + tableNumber + "\n\n" + orderContent);
```

As you can see I tried various poor attempts to solve this issue. For the actual Bluetooth code I used this guide - https://www.androidcode.ninja/android-bluetooth-tutorial/.

The printing works fine I just have an issue with spacing as described in the title.

Here is my question again - How To Print Spaces Or Left/Right Align Content On One Line From Android To Receipt Printer Over Bluetooth?

It's not a very clear question but to make it clear I want to be able to left align the item then right align the price, or use some method of space generation that will do this for me that could, for example, take into consideration the length of the item string as I have tried to do.

Ignore the Double for prices, I plan to replace it with two Integer values as I know using floats for pricing is inaccurate.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard a couple of people suggest I should use a Monospace font so I can align using spaces in the way I have above. So I have put it as the first answer to my question but I'm hoping more and potentially better answers will follow.

If this is the correct solution does anyone know an easy way to set the font when sending the data to the device?

Currently sending the String with this simple command:

```
mmOutputStream.write(data.getBytes());
```

I think this is the line that needs to be changed but it doesn't accept 'Monospace' as a definition:

```
final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
```

Ok so I was being dumb, encoding and font are different things. The question is, there must be a way to 'instruct' the printer on what font to print in and I think there is. Just not sure what that way is.

More research. I found this page with ESC/POS commands so I presume it's possible to somehow send these in the data to get what I need e.g. the tab command- https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=72

My printer isn't from this company I'm assuming ESC/POS is a standard for most printing devices like mine.

Comment: any solutions for this problem?